# Render view array programatically within template

Tags: views, theming

I would like to print the array of a specific View within a template, so I can then access each specific field and theme as I wish. The view I am using will only be outputting one row. All my attempts seem to be returning 'previously declared' errors.

Your help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: there is a `$view` variable which contains the entire View object available in most if not all Views templates, and `$views->result` contains the data in the row, so that should contain what you are looking for

Comment: Please show your code, it'll make things much easier to debug

Comment: Cool, I managed to drill down to the field I want to render:    <pre>print render($view->result[0]->field_field_media_image[0]['rendered']['#item']['uri'])</pre>

This outputs the objects content fine within the Views template, however my final objective is to have this single object render within my homepage template.

Currently, the views template block renders within a page block. Is this even the best method to render a specific view object within a page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few steps involved with applying a template to view. But thankfully they are all fairly simple.

I found one of the most helpful tutorials was [this](http://www.wdtutorials.com/drupal7/49#.UYIGTrVmh8F) one, which goes through the process. I think this process should give you sufficient control over the theme for each field.

I'm not sure why you might be getting the 'previously declared' errors though.